# Git: Rename Branch from a certain commit on

Tags: git

It was accidently commited to the wrong branch. How to rename the branch from a certain commit on?

```
IS:
--- c1 --- c2 --- c3 --- c3   branch: develop

SHOULD BE:
--- c1                        branch: develop
     \
      \
       c2 --- c3 --- c3       branch: feature/xyz
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to branch out from `develop` (feature/xyz) and reset hard with force push the `develop` branch to the `C1` commit.

Comment: (Disclaimer for future readers : this has **nothing to do** with "renaming" a branch.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `develop` branch is not referring to a remote branch, you can achieve your desired result using following steps:

**Step 1:**

Rename your current `develop` branch to `feature/xyz`

```
git branch -m feature/xyz
```

```
WILL BECOME:
--- c1 --- c2 --- c3 --- c3   branch: feature/xyz
```

**Step 2:**

Checkout the commit where you want your `develop` branch's HEAD to be. In your case, it is commit `c1`:

```
git checkout c1
```

```
WILL BECOME:
--- c1                        branch: HEAD
     \
      \
       c2 --- c3 --- c3       branch: feature/xyz
```

**Step 3:**

Create the new `develop` branch:

```
git checkout -b develop
```

```
WILL BECOME:
--- c1                        branch: develop
     \
      \
       c2 --- c3 --- c3       branch: feature/xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the suggested steps:
1. Create a New branch from the commit from which you would like to rename.

2. Merge the old branch to new branch.

Answer (score 0):

**Step one**
Create desired branch:

```sh
git checkout -b feature/xyz
```

**Step two**
Checkout proper commit and reset `develop` branch.
There are couple ways to do it (chose one most comfortable for you):

- using remote develop

```sh
git checkout -B develop origin/develop
```

- using hash of `c1`

```sh
git checkout -B develop <c1 commit hash>
```

- using third ancestor reference

```sh
git checkout -B develop HEAD~3
```

Note difference between: `-b` (create new branch) and `-B` reset existing branch.